# AbstractTableModel inheritance set column header text?

Tags: java, swing, abstracttablemodel, columnheader

I have `MyTableModel` class extent `AbstractTableModel`, How can I add the columns name and set the columns header text in the MyTableModel class itself, so I don't have to set theme everytime the model is used?

Comment: `I have MyTableModel class extent AbstractTableModel,` - why? What is wrong with the DefaultTableModel? `can I add the columns name and header text in the MyTableModel class itself,` Yes.

Comment: @camickr, I need to use AbstractTableModel to help create my table model with my entity ArrayList, this is a common way. I want to ask if there is a way to set the coumns header text, and, if have, how can I do that.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to use AbstractTableModel to help create my table model with my entity ArrayList

Check out [Row Table Model](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/). It gives a complete example of how you might do this for a Person object.

It also shows how you can create a generic entity model so that you don't have to implement all the method of the TableModel for every new entity.

Answer (score 1):

Refer following example and implement your code in proper way.

```
public class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private static final String[] COLUMN_NAMES = {"Student", "Subject", "Marks"};
    private static final Class[] COLUMN_CLASSES = {String.class, String.class, Integer.class};
    private static final Object[][] TABLE_DATA = {
        {"Channa", "Programming", 99},
        {"John", "English", 85},
        {"Samantha", "Scence", 60},
        {"Kumar", "Maths", 90}
    };

    //the column header
    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        return COLUMN_NAMES[column];
    }

    //if you want to change the columns class 
    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        return COLUMN_CLASSES[columnIndex];
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return TABLE_DATA.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return COLUMN_NAMES.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return TABLE_DATA[rowIndex][columnIndex];
    }
}
```

Here is my testing screenshot

[image]

Comment: `I need to use AbstractTableModel to help create my table model with my entity ArrayList,` - how does this help with the "entities in the ArrayList?